# Dynamic create rows and colum with the help of PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

I want to create dynamic rows and column with the help of PHP and HTML but I am little  confused about this code so some help is definitely appreciated.

```
<table>
<?php
  $tr = 0;
  foreach ($data as $db_data) {
    $tr++;
    if ($tr == 1) {
      echo "<tr>";
      }

    echo "<td>";
    echo $db_data['id'];
    echo "</td>";
    }

  if($tr == 2){

    }
?>
</table>
```

Scenario is so simple:

Mysql data return 6 no of records from for-each loop the result will be show like this image

[image]

Same way the Mysql data return 3 no of records the result will be show like this image

[image]

Comment: What `$data` looks like?

Comment: @pinkypower my Q is how to print like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe

### function create_table()

```
function create_table($data) {
  $res = '<table width="200" border="1">';
  $max_data = sizeof($data);
  $ctr = 1;
  foreach ($data as $db_data) {
    if ($ctr % 2 == 0) $res .= '<td align="center">' . $db_data['id']. '</td></tr>';
    else {
      if ($ctr < $max_data) $res .= '<tr><td align="center">' . $db_data['id']. '</td>';
      else $res .= '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">' . $db_data['id']. '</td></tr>';
      }
    $ctr++;
    }
  return $res . '</table>';
  }
```

Course, you can modify style of table to fit your needs.

Call it like this:

```
echo create_table($data);
```

### Output

(example for 7, 4, 3 and 8 **id**'s)
[image]

It returns table with same number of rowsin each column if you pass even number of id's or table where last row is merged if you pass odd number of id's into function.

Comment: I checked your code using this http://codepad.org/rJGZa3Me and i got my answer thanx for sharing me your experience

Comment: A thorough answer, even with a screenshot - nice. But the melding of html strings with loop logic is probably non-optimal - shouldn't we be encouraging their separation into a template layer, using single-line PHP statements?

Comment: i know this but using @Wh1T3h4Ck5 his answer to provide me logic not an whole functionality

Comment: Well, I expect it will be helpful for someone `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Use % php operator (division remainder) to break rows where you need

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
  foreach ($data as $ord => $db_data)
  {
      if (($ord == count($data) - 1) && (count($data) % 2))
      {
          // Do a colspan of 2, as it is the last item (first clause)
          // and there are an odd number of items (second clause)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is a good idea to count an array on each loop iteration? twice?

Comment: You'll not notice any speed improvement taking it outside of the loop with data of this size, imo. But, sure, it could be done.

Comment: I agree, there will be no difference for small amount of data. But someone may consider it as a pattern even for large arrays :)

Comment: Well, it's an edit free-for-all here. I shalln't mind if you make that improvement `:)`

Comment: Incidentally, the reason I stuffed everything into one line, rather than breaking out with `$count = count($data)` is that this is template-layer stuff. In practise I'd switch the `foreach` and the `if` to the colon style, and wrap each of them in PHP tags. That way, the rendering logic is kept light, and the IDE can make sense of the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try doing it in a while loop . 
for example

```
$sql = your.sql.query;
$row = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_arrey($row)
<table>
while($row!=0) {
echo "
<tr>
// number of <td> you need according to your data return in the query:
<td>$result['column']</td>
<td>$result['column']</td>
</tr>
";
}
```

if i understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way. This one uses Bootstrap syntax, but you can easily change it to a `table` format or anything else. Logic is the same. Remember to update the `$items` array name with your own where appropriate.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        // Sample array
        $items = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

        // Define how many columns
        $cols = 4;

        $tdCount = 1; // Don't change
        foreach ($items as $key => $item)
        {
            ?>

            <div class="col"><?php echo $key; ?></div>

            <?php
            // Close and open new rows
            if( (($key + 1) % $cols) === 0  && ($key + 1) !== count($items) )
            {
                ?>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <?php
            }

            // Increment column count
            $tdCount++;

            // Fill with empty columns at the end
            if( ($key + 1) === count($items) && $tdCount <= $cols )
            {
                $spacers = $cols - $tdCount;
                for ($i = $spacers; $i >= 0 ; $i--)
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <?php
                }
            }

            // Reset columns count
            if( $tdCount > $cols )
            {
                $tdCount = 1;
            }
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will output:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">0</div>
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
        <div class="col">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">8</div>
        <div class="col">9</div>
        <div class="col spacer">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```