# How To Create Rows & Columns using php and html

Tags: php, html

I need to create the rows columns like this:

[image]

This is  testing code im just implementing the logic for snapshot.

source code

```
    $data = array('early','early','comment1','comment2','20','30');


   function create_table($data)
   {
   $res = '<table width="200" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">';
   $max_data = sizeof($data);
   $ctr = 1;
      foreach ($data as $db_data)
      {
            if ($ctr % 2 == 0) $res .= '<td>' . $db_data. '</td></tr>';
              else
              {
              if ($ctr < $max_data) $res .= '<tr><td>' . $db_data. '</td>';
               else $res .= '<tr><td colspan="2">' . $db_data. '</td></tr>';
              }
            $ctr++;
      }
      return $res . '</table>';
   }

 echo create_table($data);
```

html

```
          <h2>Entry Fee</h2>

        <table border="0" class="tb not-mobile">
        <tr>
        <td width="30%" rowspan="3">Early (Payment received by 1/4/15) </td>
        <td width="58%">MD/DO</td>
        <td width="12%" class="aligncenter">$23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td>CRNA/PA</td>
        <td class="aligncenter">$37</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>RESIDENT/RN/OTHERS</td>
        <td class="aligncenter">$49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Early (Payment received by 1/4/15) </td>
        <td>MD/DO</td>
        <td class="aligncenter">$23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td>CRNA/PA</td>
        <td class="aligncenter">$37</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>RESIDENT/RN/OTHERS</td>
        <td class="aligncenter">$49</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

- this raw html that snapshot shows.
- i trying build same logic similar as snapshot.

array structure

```
        Array
        (
        [0] => Array(
        [type] => General Public Tickets Adult
        [metadata] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
        [amount] => 50
        [comment] => (Working Days)
        )
        [1] => Array(
        [amount] => 80
        [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
        )
        )
        )

        [1] => Array(
        [type] => Special Tickets Children
        [metadata] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
        [amount] => 300
        [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
        )
        [1] => Array(
        [amount] => 10000
        [comment] => (Monday afternoon)
        )
        )
        )
        )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821103/dynamic-create-rows-and-colum-with-the-help-of-php-and-html

Comment: yup but i refer link to but unable to make logic some like snapshot

Comment: If by "dynamic" you means to make the programm display the information when they arrives (in this case, paiements which come if I correctly understood), you can't do this by using only php and html because those 2 langages are not dynamic, which means each of those lines are "read" by the webrowser, and cannot be read twice or more. You can do so by implementing javascript.

Comment: i just need to create similar logic as same as snapshot

Comment: case 1 . when type =is greater then 1 or comment >1

Comment: i just trying build similar as raw html as shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible the way you want it to be done. You have to create a 2D array and get the data from that. 
Here is an example:

```
<?php
// On the line below, create your own associative array:
$myArray = array (  'Early (Payment received by 1/4/15)' => array('MD/DO', '$23','RNA/PA', '$37','RESIDENT/RN/OTHERS', '$49'),
                    'Early (Payment received by 1/4/15) ' => array('MD/DO', '$23','RNA/PA', '$37','RESIDENT/RN/OTHERS', '$49'));

// On the line below, loop through the array and output
// *all* of the values to the page:
print '<table width="800" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">';
foreach ($myArray as $place => $task) 
{
    print "<tr><td rowspan='4'>".$place."</td></tr>";
    $i = 0;
    print "<tr>";
    foreach ($task as $thingToDo)
    {
        $i++;
        if ($i == 2)
        {
            print "<td>".$thingToDo."</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            $i = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            print "<td>".$thingToDo."</td>";
        }
    }
}
print " </table>";
?>
```

Output:
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: can you help when array structure that i have updated what changes should i have t do according updated array structure