# php post as side by side

Tags: php, jquery

in my project dynamically creating list of

's as heading category and its images.like

```
<li>Heading 1</li>
<li>Image 1</li>
<li>Image 2</li>
<li>Image 3</li>
<li>Image 4</li>
<li>Image 5</li>

<li>Heading 2</li>
<li>Image 1</li>
<li>Image 2</li>
<li>Image 3</li>

<li>Heading 3</li>
<li>Image 1</li>
```

Each heading is a category and image names are images under each category.
Now its coming one by one and i want to display it as side by side as shown in image.

[image]

Like in image one heading and 2 images below and next li side to heading.if li under one category finises next heading comes to new column.

How can i create a table like in image using php. each heading and and its images.

Comment: use `table` element you get like this

Comment: yes but how can i contol li as new when list under one category completed

Comment: why should you use `li` ?

Comment: the images are dynamic or static ? whatever use grid like table no bother about 'li` also no need

Comment: images and category names all are dynamic..i want to show in a slider so want to display as li's

Comment: `slider` ??? or table format ?? i am confusing

Comment: how can i implement using table

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Table then the html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <td>Image 3</td>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <td>Image 3</td>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 1</td>
        <td>Image 4</td>
        <td>Image 1</td>
        <td>Image 4</td>
        <td>Image 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 2</td>
        <td>Image 5</td>
        <td>Image 2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**This is a simple trick: example**

```
<?php
    $images = array('Image 1', 'Image 2', 'Image 3', 'Image 4', 'Image 5'); 
    $fixRow = 3;  //total fixed row that you want

    $L1 = 5;/*List-1 item*/ $L1C = ceil(($L1+1)/$fixRow);// 2 row for 1st list
    $L2 = 3;/*List-2 item*/ $L2C = ceil(($L2+1)/$fixRow);//2 row for 2nd list
    $L3 = 1;/*List-3 item*/ $L3C = ceil(($L3+1)/$fixRow);//1 row for 3rd list

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php
            //list-1 column=2  
            $k=0;
            for ($i=0; $i<$L1C ; $i++){ 
                if($i==0){
                    echo "<th>Heading 1</th>";
                }else{ 
                    echo "<td>".$images[$k-1]."</td>";
                }
                $k = $k+$fixRow;
            }  

            //list-2 column=2 
            $k=0;
            for ($i=0; $i<$L2C ; $i++){ 
                if($i==0){
                    echo "<th>Heading 2</th>";
                }else{ 
                    echo "<td>".$images[$k-1]."</td>";
                }
                $k = $k+$fixRow;
            } 

            //list-3 column=1  
            $k=0;
            for ($i=0; $i<$L3C ; $i++){ 
                if($i==0){
                    echo "<th>Heading 3</th>";
                }else{ 
                    echo "<td>".$images[$k-1]."</td>";
                }
                $k = $k+$fixRow;
            } 
        ?>
    </tr>

    <?php for ($j=0; $j <2 ; $j++){
        echo "<tr>";
            $k=$j;
            for ($i=0; $i<$L1C ; $i++) { 
                if($i==0){
                    if($j<$L1){
                        echo "<td>".$images[$j]."</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }else{ 
                    if($k<$L1){
                        echo "<td>".$images[$k]."</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }
                $k = $k+$fixRow;
            } 

            $k=$j;
            for ($i=0; $i<$L2C ; $i++) {
                if($i==0){
                    if($j<$L2){
                        echo "<td>".$images[$j]."</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }else{ 
                    if($k<$L2){
                        echo "<td>".$images[$k]."</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }

                $k = $k+$fixRow;
            } 

            $k=$j;
            for ($i=0; $i<$L3C ; $i++) {
                if($i==0){
                    if($j<$L3){
                        echo "<td>".$images[$j]."</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }else{ 
                    if($k<$L3){
                        echo "<td>".$images[$k]."</td>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }
                $k = $k+$fixRow;
            } 
        echo "</tr>";
    } ?>
</table>
```

> You can modify by using common function

Comment: how can i restrict only 3 rows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821103/dynamic-create-rows-and-colum-with-the-help-of-php-and-html